# Modal window scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the modal window (bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">            
<div class="modal-dialog">                    
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            TEXT
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="NEXT" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2"/></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By clicking on "NEXT" button, #modal1 is closing and #modal2 is opening:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2">            
<div class="modal-dialog">                    
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            TITLE
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            TEXT //lots of text
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="EXIT" data-dismiss="modal"/></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scrolling is working fine in the first modal window #modal1, but in the #modal2 it is not working, there is not even the scrollbar. 
**So, the question is: How to make the scrolling work in the second window?**

**UPD: added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/386ozdb7/2/**

Comment: added, look to the UPD

Comment: Since you don't use any script other than including bootstrap and jquery this is probably a bug in bootstrap and not in your code.

Comment: pstenstrm, anyway, i would like to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code correctly you can see that div with class "modal-footer" are not inside the div with "modal-content" as the documentation suggest. Maybe that can be the problem of scrollbar with a lot of text

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">            
    <div class="modal-dialog">                    
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                TEXT
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="NEXT" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2"/></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try to change your 2 modals as below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">            
    <div class="modal-dialog">                    
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                TEXT
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form><input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="NEXT" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#modal2"/></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check the bootstrap example at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

ps: always indent your code.. it's useful to reduce markup error!

Comment: no, i just updated jsfiddle, it is now the problem. i think, there is some conflict between styles, but i don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Thats the problem: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#overlapping-modals-not-supported

***Overlapping modals not supported***

*Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.*

This may help you: https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

Comment: I close the #modal1 before opening the #modal2, so it shouldn't be the problem

Comment: closing modal1 and opening modal2 happens in the same event, so i think thats the problem

Comment: Is there any way to seperate these actions, but eing not visible to user?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
.modal {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .modal-open {
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty skimpy.  Where should the OP add this? How will this help?

Comment: As long as you read the question and took the time to understand the problem and answer, could you perhaps also take the time to explain *why* this is the solution? That would help people much more than a dry piece of CSS code.